# javascript function to concatenate characters after pressing submit button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a webpage containing some buttons having an alphabet each as their value and a submit button. When the submit button is pressed all the letters should be concatenated in a string.
For this, I have written following snippet. But it doesn't work. (It gives undefined value.)

Also after myFunction.word is returned, I want to set it to " " so that for next set of characters it begin with fresh alphabets.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(a) {
    this.word = '';
    if(a == ''){
         return myFunction.word;
    }
    else{
        myFunction.word += a;
        return '';
    }
}
</script>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('a')">
A</button>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('b')">
B</button>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('c')">
C</button>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('')">
Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
---------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple solution, I would suggest:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" class="letter">A</button>
<button type="button" class="letter">B</button>
<button type="button" class="letter">C</button>

<button type="button" 
      onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = word; word = '';">
    Submit
</button>

<script>
    var word = "";
    var letters = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
    for (var i=0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        letters[i].onclick = function (evt) {
            word += evt.target.innerHTML;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
function myFunction(a) {
  if (!myFunction.word || a === "") {
    myFunction.temp = myFunction.word;
    myFunction.word = "";        
  };
  if (a.length >= 1) { myFunction.word += a };

  return a.length >= 1 ? "" : myFunction.temp;
};
```

```js
function myFunction(a) {
  if (!myFunction.word || a === "") {
    myFunction.temp = myFunction.word;
    myFunction.word = "";
    
  };
  if (a.length >= 1) { myFunction.word += a };

  return a.length >= 1 ? "" : myFunction.temp;
};
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('a')">
  A</button>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('b')">
  B</button>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('c')">
  C</button>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction('')">
  Submit</button>
```

Comment: Wow. What a fancy way of doing things... :)